# how to write hadoop map reduce programs in scala

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, mapreduce

I am writing a map reduce application scala. Till map function everything works fine. But while writing the reducer I am facing problem.

```
override def reduce(key: Text, values: java.lang.Iterable[Text], 
                    context: ReducerContext) {
}
```

The `ReducerContext` is defined such that is refers to the context inner class, so I am fine here.

The issue is with the `Iterable` (Java) component.I am not able to iterate through it.
I understand that first I have convert it into a scala `Iterable` and then iterate over it, I also did that but still didnt get get result.

I have tried both scala.collection.JavaConverters._ and JavaConversions._ 
here are few scanarios that didnt work out

```
val jit: java.util.Iterator[Text]= values.iterator()
val abc = JavaConversions.asScalaIterator(jit) /// val abc=jit.asScala
println("size "+ abc.size)// it displays proper size
for(temp <- abc){
///it dosent come inside this loop
}
```

Similarly I have tried converting this Iterator into list/array but all in vain. Once i convert it into list/arrray(toList/tiArray) the size of the resulting list/array becomes 0.
no matter what I do m not able to iterate thorough

I appreciate any help on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import `JavaConversions` to convert `Iterable` automatically.

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
```

If you still have any problem, can you paste your codes?

The tricky thing of `values` which you receive in the `reduce` is that it only can be traversed once. `abc.size` will traverse the `values`. After that, `values` is invalid.

So the correct code should be

```
// don't use values
for(value <- values) {
    // do something
    val v = value.toString
    // Don't save value, it will be reused. The content of value will be changed but the reference is same.
}
// don't use values
```

Just like I mentioned in the comment, the type of `value` is `Text`. When you traverse `values`, the content of `value` will be changed, but the reference is same. So don't try to save `value` in a `Collection`, or you will get a `Collection` that all of the items are same.

Comment: The tricky thing of `values` which you receive in the reducer is that it only can be traversed once. `abc.size` will traverse the `values`. After that, `values` is invalid.

Comment: Removing `println("size "+ abc.size)// it displays proper size` should work.